# Colimits of ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

I'm reading a few commutative algebra books right now and noticed that many texts take filtered colimits (direct limits) of ideals of different rings, but never really seem to actually say where they're taking the colimits. To fix a concrete example, suppose that $ R \colon A \to \mathbf{CRing} $ is a filtered diagram of commutative rings, that $ I(\alpha) \subset R(\alpha) $  is an ideal for each object $ \alpha $ in $ A $, and that for each morphism $ \iota_{\alpha\beta} \colon \alpha \to \beta $ in $ A $  we have $ F(\iota_{\alpha\beta})(I_\alpha) \subset I_\beta $, and consider "the colimit $ \operatorname{colim}_{\alpha \in A} I_\alpha $". I'm interested in knowing where people usually take such a colimit.

I've assumed that this is taking place in the category of abelian groups ($ \mathbb{Z} $-modules) as this makes the most sense, for many reasons. Is this what is generally implicitly assumed?

Comment: It turns out not to especially matter, since the various implicit forgetful functors here preserve filtered colimits. But the pedantic answer would be that these colimits are happening in the category of ideals (which is a poset).

Comment: @ZhenLin In your comment you're just talking about colimits of ideals in the same ring, correct? I actually meant of ideals of different rings.

Comment: Ah. Well, then it would have to be abelian groups, or the category of pairs (ideal, ring), depending on what kinds of homomorphisms you are thinking of.